# Filter \n in a String in java

Tags: java, terminal, equals

I have this simple code:

```
BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    while (true) {
        String tmp = bR.readLine();
        System.out.println(tmp);

        if (!tmp.contains("\n")) {
            PrintWriter pW = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            pW.printf("return message: " + tmp);
        }
```

My problem is, that when I use `Enter` in my Terminal, still "return message" is printed to the terminal (Telnet in that case)
Also when I try `tmp.equals("\n")` it doesn't catch the `Enter`. 
What can I do to catch the a `Enter` that `return message` is not printed out?

Comment: think of Enter as character in split method. you will never get it in your tmp variable

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly the condition should be `if (!tmp.isEmpty())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `readLine()`of the `BufferedReader`class gets terminated on the occurence of a newline `\n`.

This means a `\n`cannot be in `tmp`.

For reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29

Comment: thank you (y) i solved it now with if (tmp.length() > 0) thanks to your hint :)